# User input in Factorial Recursion?

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, factorial

So I'm trying to make a program where the user inputs a number and the computer outputs the factorial. I have to use recursion and have 1 class and 1 client.

My class is:

```
public class Factorial 
{ 
   public static int Factorial(int n)
   {
      if(n==1)
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return n*(Factorial(n-1));
      }
   }
}
```

My client is:

```
public class FactorialClient
{
    public static void main()
   {
      Factorial n = new Factorial();
      System.out.println(n.Factorial(4));
   }
}
```

These both compile and work completely fine. However, I'm trying to figure out a way for the user to input the number instead of my inputting the number inside the client. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class FactorialClient
{
    public static void main()
   {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      int x = reader.nextInt();
      Factorial n = new Factorial();
      System.out.println(n.Factorial(x));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class is great for reading user input.

The following should work:

```
public class FactorialClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Factorial.Factorial(userInput));

  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to declare a new Factorial object because the Factorial method has been declared static.